# Python: 'super' object has no attribute 'attribute_name'

Tags: python, attributes, super

I am trying to access a variable from the base class. Here's the parent class:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.some_var = value
```

And here's the child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(Child, self).__init__(value)

    def doSomething(self):
        parent_var = super(Child, self).some_var
```

Now, if I try to run this code:

```
obj = Child(123)
obj.doSomething()
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    obj.doSomething()
  File "test.py", line 10, in doSomething
    parent_var = super(Child, self).some_var
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'some_var'
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the recommended way to access variables from the base class in Python?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After the base class's `__init__` ran, the derived object has the attributes set there (e.g. `some_var`) as it's the very same object as the `self` in the derived class' `__init__`. You can and should just use `self.some_var` everywhere. `super` is for accessing stuff from base classes, but instance variables are (as the name says) part of an instance, not part of that instance's class.

Answer (score 7):

The attribute some_var does not exist in the Parent class.

When you set it during `__init__`, it was created in the instance of your Child class.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, and it was a silly mistake

```
class one:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
    def status(self):
        print("This is from 1")
```

This was my parent class

```
class two:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
    def status(self):
        super().status()
        print("This is from 2")
```

This was the child class

```
a = one()
a.status()

b = two()
b.status()
```

I was getting same error

```
init
This is from 1
init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in status
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'status'
>
```

The problem was, I was not entering argument after declaring class two,
"class two:" should be "class two(one)"
so the solution was.

```
class two(one):
def __init__(self):
    print("init")
def status(self):
    super().status()
    print("This is from 2")
```